# Calculate distance of Google Map polyline when polyline snaps to street

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code that when the map is clicked draws a route that snaps to the road. What I am wanting to do is find the length/distance between each marker on the polyline that is stored in an array and incremented each time a new marker is clicked, so at the end the total distance traveled can be shown. I have tried a few examples found on different sites however none seem to fit into the code I actually have.

I am looking through the Google Maps API documentation now and have stumbled across this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#DistanceMatrixRequest however there are no examples of how it potentially works.

```
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {

if (path.getLength() === 0) {
  path.push(evt.latLng);
  poly.setPath(path);
} else {
  service.route({
    origin: path.getAt(path.getLength() - 1),
    destination: evt.latLng,

    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length;
          i < len; i++) {
        path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);

      }
    }
  });
}
var latitude_longitude = evt.latLng;
alert(latitude_longitude);////Gets latitude and Longitude - Latitude first - Longitude second

  });
```

A working example of what currently happens can be found [here](http://homepages.shu.ac.uk/~b1004317/fyp/map.php)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the length of the polyline, sum the distance between all the vertices:

```
var distance = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength() - 2; i++) {
  distance += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(path.getAt(i), path.getAt(i + 1));
}
alert(distance / 1000).toFixed(2) + " km [" + path.getLength() + "]");
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9fdzyjL/)

working code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var poly;
var path;
var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map
  });
  path = poly.getPath();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {
    var latitude_longitude = evt.latLng;
    // alert(latitude_longitude); ////Gets latitude and Longitude - Latitude first - Longitude second

    if (path.getLength() === 0) {
      path.push(evt.latLng);
      poly.setPath(path);
    } else {
      service.route({
        origin: path.getAt(path.getLength() - 1),
        destination: evt.latLng,

        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);

          }
          var distance = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength() - 2; i++) {
            distance += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(path.getAt(i), path.getAt(i + 1));
          }
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = (distance / 1000).toFixed(2) + " km [" + path.getLength() + "]";

        }
      });
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: is it applicable when using Snap-To-Roads?